# "Unable to restore previously selected frame" when looping through NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsarray, nsdictionary

I got the following errors in my app:

```
warning:Unable to restore previously selected frame
warning:Unable to restore previously selected frame
```

when using the following code:

```
NSDictionary *feed = [json_parser objectWithString:json_str error:nil];
for(NSDictionary *feed_item in [feed objectForKey:@"items"])
{
    PropertyData *propertyData; // mere data model class with properties only,no methods
    [propertyData release];
}
```

with this line hightlighted **Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"**

```
[propertyData release];
```

the json string looks like the following before parsing (so you may understand how data are structured, the parsing works fine though):

```
{
    "total":110,"page":1,
    "items":[
        {"pid":"1349","price":"52,000","type":"Apartment","beds":"","descr1":"<p></p>"},
        {"pid":"1349","price":"52,000","type":"Apartment","beds":"","descr1":"<p></p>"},
        {"pid":"1349","price":"52,000","type":"Apartment","beds":"","descr1":"<p></p>"}
    ]
}
```

Any idea of what's wrong ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: Could you post the crash log / stack trace here as well?

Comment: It's only "warning:Unable to restore previously selected frame" many times nothing more

Comment: I found what was the issue:

    PropertyData *propertyData;

It should have been:

    PropertyData *propertyData = [[PropertyData alloc] init];

In short, allocation before using...

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating/initializing PropertyData. The pointer is referring to some random place in memory, and then you are sending it "release" message which causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS,