# How to Add a table view as a sub view which is also a subview of main view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am new to iOS please help me.

I am trying to add subview,which has a table view in my main view.After connecting the data source and delegate after building the application it crashes.

with warning:Unable to restore previously selected frame.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385685/unable-to-restore-previously-selected-frame-when-looping-through-nsdictionary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349149/app-crash-with-unable-to-restore-previously-selected-frame-message

Comment: Please once read my problem completely.

Comment: I did, and your problem is completely unrelated to a subview.  Have you read the linked answers or googled you problem?  Because I got at least 10 helpful results when I googled your error alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

Make a TableView using initWithFrame: and set your frame as you may want it to be.

Confirm to the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.
Set the TableView's datasource and delegate to self.
Add all the necessary method for delegate and datasource.
[yourMainVeiw addSubview:yourTableView];
then [yourTableView removeFromSuperView]; where ever necessary.
I believe you have already done most of it. but in case if you forgot to add a step.
I hope it helps you!!